# Android Actionbar shows no items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new to android and have this problem for while: No item appear on action bar, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Here is my menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.myappshop.myapp.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"
        android:title="@string/share"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

And the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    EditText mEditTextWord;
    EditText mEditTextDefinition;
    DictionaryDatabase mDB;
    ListView mListView;

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB = new DictionaryDatabase(this);
        mEditTextWord = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextWord);
        mEditTextDefinition = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDefinition);
        Button buttonAddUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddUpdate);

        buttonAddUpdate.setOnClickListener(
                new  View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        saveRecord();
                    }
                });



        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
                    view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "the id is logged " + Long.toString(id));

                String nextId = String.valueOf(id+1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key" ,mDB.getWord(id)+"");
                intent.putExtra("value",mDB.getDefinition(id)+"");
                intent.putExtra("nextId",nextId+"");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Records deleted = " + mDB.deleteRecord(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateWordList();
                return true;
            }
        });
        updateWordList();

    }


    private void saveRecord() {
        mDB.saveRecord(mEditTextWord.getText().toString(),
                mEditTextDefinition.getText().toString());
        mEditTextWord.setText("");
        mEditTextDefinition.setText("");
        updateWordList();
    }

    private void updateWordList() {
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new
                SimpleCursorAdapter( this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mDB.getWordList(),
                new String[]{"word"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);
        mListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    }


    @Override  //added following https://stackoverflow.com/a/27192897/5774375 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myappshop.myapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The minimum API that I'v set is 15.
I've looked at similar answers on SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192848/actionbar-up-navigation-not-working-on-api-15) but none resolve my probelm. So appreciate your help.

UPDATE: DetailActivity.java added:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button shareBtn, nextBtn, prevBtn, indexBtn ;
    DictionaryDatabase mDB;
    TextView title, body; //Globally Declaration
    String nextId;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        try{
            String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
            String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
            String idString = getIntent().getStringExtra("nextId");
            id = Integer.parseInt(idString) + 1;  //to be used to rener the next item


            title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(key);

            body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
            body.setText(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.getText().toString());
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });
        shareBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);


        //render the next word
        mDB = new DictionaryDatabase(this);
        nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        prevBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevBtn);
        indexBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.indexBtn);

        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id+=1;
                Log.d(TAG, "the next item to be fetched has id: " + Long.toString(id));

                Log.d(TAG, "return value is: " + mDB.getWord(id));
                if (mDB.getWord(id) != "") {
                    String key = mDB.getWord(id);
                    String value = mDB.getDefinition(id);

                    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                    title.setText(key);

                    body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
                    body.setText(value);
                    prevBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                        finish();
                }
            }
        });

        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id-=1;
                if (mDB.getWord(id) != "") {
                    String key = mDB.getWord(id);
                    String value = mDB.getDefinition(id);

                    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                    title.setText(key);

                    body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
                    body.setText(value);
                    nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });

        indexBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inflate your menu.xml before you can call its menu items. Add this before `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Sorry about that. I also noticed that you didn't declare your toolbar in your activitys' onCreate(). You would have to declare your toolbar before placing menu items on it. Add this to your activity's onCreate method.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Also, make sure you include your toolbar/appbar layout in your main layout for this activity.

Comment: I added the code above before `onOptionsItemSelected` but the item did not appear. In addition to that now when I click each word, the app hangs.

Comment: Yes, after adding these I can see the menu items. Thank you!

Comment: @Karlom No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Sorry, I still have an issue. I also added the very same code above to my `DetailActivity`, which shows each word with definition. But now when each word is tapped, the app hangs. Any thought on that?

Comment: @Karlom Hmm. I'd have to see your detail class to see where the issue is. Are you using the same menu xml? I used different ones for each additional class including my detail class. I also declared this after setSupportToolbar `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: @Karlom Also make sure you "include" your appbar layout in your detail layout. `<include layout=@layout/your_app_bar />`

Comment: That's alright Steve. The issue resolved. I had mistakenly added a line to the detail.xml. Thanks again.